# UIKit cell animation with UIContentConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I face into weird animation behaviour when I try to implement `UIContentConfiguration` for my `UITableView`.

I've implemented simple downscale animation on touch for my cell, but it doesn't work as expected. `UILabel` upscale first, and after that downscale.
I realized that animation behaviour related with updating configuration when touch began.
I've found that app has to call `setNeedsUpdateConfiguration` in animation block, but all my attempts have failed.

[image]

Code samples below: 
**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var array: [String]  = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
    
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(MyCustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCell")
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
        return table
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController:  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        array.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomTableViewCell {
            cell.configure(configuration: AnimatableContentViewConfiguration(text: array[indexPath.row]))
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }    
}
```

**MyCustomCell.swift**

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    func configure(configuration: AnimatableContentViewConfiguration) {
        contentConfiguration = configuration
    }
}
```

**AnimatableContentViewConfiguration.swift**

```
struct AnimatableContentViewConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
   
    fileprivate var titleText: String = ""
 
    init(text: String) {
    titleText = text
    }
    
    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        AnimatableContentView(configuration: self)
    }
    
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> AnimatableContentViewConfiguration {
        self
    }
}
```

**AnimatableContentView.swift**

```
final class AnimatableContentView: UIView, UIContentView {
    

    
    private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        UILabel(frame: .init(x: 5, y: 5, width: 100, height: 20))
    }()
    
   
    
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
        didSet {
            if let configuration = configuration as? AnimatableContentViewConfiguration {
                configure(configuration)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    required init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
    }
    
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
    func configure(_ configuration: AnimatableContentViewConfiguration) {
        titleLabel.text = configuration.titleText
    }
    
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        highlight(true)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        highlight(false)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        highlight(false)
    }

    
    
    func highlight(_ touched: Bool) {
        highlight(touched, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func highlight(_ touched: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
      
        
        let scaleSize = 0.97
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleSize, y: scaleSize)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,
                       options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseIn],
                       animations: {
            self.transform = touched ? transform : .identity
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate for any help with my issue.